# Passing array of FILE type to function = Segmentation fault

Tags: c, gcc

Following code passes a pointer to an array of type FILE, in to a function, causing a segmentation fault when the array is accessed (gcc, on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS).

In main, have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

FILE **ptr_rdfile;

//Function declares
FILE ** open_files(int argc, char *argv[]);
int parse_files(FILE **ptr_rdfile[], int argc, char *argv[]);

//check for required input
if( argc < 2 )
   {
   printf( "Error - must enter at least one binary filename to read in.\n" );
   return 1;
   }

if( argc > 5 )
   {
   printf( "Error - maximum number of binary filenames %d.\n", MAX_FILES );
   return 1;
   }

//open files specified on cmd line
ptr_rdfile = open_files(argc, argv);
if( ptr_rdfile == NULL ) 
  {
  printf( "Exiting program\n" );
  return 1;
  }

//parse file contents into corresponding array of structs, print to stdout
  if( parse_files(&ptr_rdfile, argc, argv) !=0 )
    {
    printf( "Parse Failed - Exiting program\n" );
    return 1;
}
```

Function open_files is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

FILE ** open_files(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
  int i;
  FILE **ptr_rdfile;

  ptr_rdfile = malloc( sizeof(FILE *) * (argc-1));

  if( ptr_rdfile == NULL )
    {
    printf("Error: Not enough memory\n");
    getchar();
    return NULL;
    } 

  i=1;
  for( i=1; i<argc; i++)
    {    
    errno=0;
    ptr_rdfile[i-1] = fopen(argv[i],"rb");
    //printf( "ptr_rdfile[%d]:%p\n", (i-1), ptr_rdfile[i-1]);
    if (!ptr_rdfile[i-1])
      {
      printf( "Unable to open file - is file name correct???   Errno = %d,  %s.\n", errno, strerror(errno) );
      return NULL;
      }
    } 

  return ptr_rdfile;
  }
```

Function parse_files is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

int parse_files(FILE **ptr_rdfile[], int argc, char *argv[])
  {
  unsigned int j;
  signed int i;

  struct prod_rec
    {
    int ver;
    char type_code[20];
    unsigned int unit_ID;   
    float price;
    };

  struct prod_rec prod[argc];

  i=0;
  for( i=0; i<argc-1; i++)
    { 
    //printf( "fread: i = %d", i );
    if (fread(&prod[i], sizeof(struct prod_rec), 1, *ptr_rdfile[i]) != 1) 
      {
      printf( "error writing sturct:  Errno = %d,  %s.\n", errno, strerror(errno) );
      }
    }
}
```

Running with the following printf (and various iterations of) in main just before call to parse_file,

```
printf( "parse_files: ptr_rdfile = %p\n *ptr_rdfile = %p\n ptr_rdfile[0] = %p\n ptr_rdfile[1] = %p\n (void*)&ptr_rdfile[0] = %p\n (void*)&ptr_rdfile[1] = %p\n *ptr_rdfile[0] = %p\n *ptr_rdfile[1] = %p\n, **ptr_rdfile = %p\n **ptr_rdfile[1] = %p\n", ptr_rdfile, *ptr_rdfile, ptr_rdfile[0], ptr_rdfile[1], (void*)&ptr_rdfile[0], (void*)&ptr_rdfile[1], *ptr_rdfile[0], *ptr_rdfile[1], **ptr_rdfile, **ptr_rdfile );
```

shows shows the following:

```
 ptr_rdfile = 0x804c008
 *ptr_rdfile = 0x804c018
 ptr_rdfile[0] = 0x804c018
 ptr_rdfile[1] = 0x804c180
 (void*)&ptr_rdfile[0] = 0x804c008
 (void*)&ptr_rdfile[1] = 0x804c00c
```

Stepping into parse_files from main, with gdb, ptr_rdfile has the following:

```
(gdb) print ptr_rdfile[1]
$1 = (FILE **) 0xb7e52e55
(gdb) print *ptr_rdfile
$2 = (FILE **) 0x804c008
(gdb) print **ptr_rdfile
$3 = (FILE *) 0x804c018
(gdb) print ***ptr_rdfile
$4 = {_flags = -72539000, ...    
print *ptr_rdfile[1]
$11 = (FILE *) 0x5b18c483
```

Looking beyond my thrashing around above, I think it appears the ptr_rdfile[0] came in ok, but not ptr_rdfile[1].

I also tried the following format for ptr_rdfile:

```
//function declare:
  int parse_files(FILE ***ptr_rdfile, int argc, char *argv[]);
function call:
  if( parse_files(&ptr_rdfile, argc, argv) !=0 )
```

Above caused same error.

Before I moved the above code into parse_files, I had that code in main, and it worked correctly with the same declare of ptr_rdfile, and the following call to fread:

```
if (fread(&prod[i], sizeof(struct prod_rec), 1, ptr_rdfile[i]) != 1)
```

Moving to a separate function, based on discussions I researched on this site re. passing arrays of pointers to functions, I came away with the above attempts, but I'm apparently missing something  here...

Any debug suggestions appreciated.

Thank you.

UPDATE:
I had tried something like @user3629249 suggested, which had resulted in the following compile warning:

```
$ gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -o parsebin.out open_files.c parse_files.c parsebin.c
parsebin.c: In function ‘main’:
parsebin.c:41:3: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘parse_files’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
parsebin.c:17:7: note: expected ‘struct FILE **’ but argument is of type ‘struct FILE ***’
```

I just tried again with the following code (func declare, func call, and function code):

In main:

```
//func declare:
int parse_files(FILE **ptr_myfile, int argc, char *argv[]);

//func call:
if( parse_files(ptr_myfile, argc, argv) !=0 )
```

In parse_files:

```
int parse_files(FILE **ptr_myfile, int argc, char *argv[])
  {
  ...
   if (fread(&prod[i], sizeof(struct prod_rec), 1, ptr_myfile[i]) != 1)
```

Well, dang, I must have messed up something in that earlier attempt cuz the above seems to work ok. Whew, thank you user3629249 and everyone else for the kind help and guidance. With the help, I think I understand the pointer scheme here. Thank you again.

Comment: I haven't actually looked at your problem, but have an upvote anyway just for (gasp!), actually doing some debugging and posting what you found.

Comment: the `passed pointer to an array[] of FILE` should be `passed pointer to an array[] of FILE*`

Comment: this expression: `FILE **ptr_rdfile[]` is the same as `FILE ***ptr_rdfile` while I think you actually want: `FILE **ptr_rdfile`  (just 2 '*')

Comment: Please post the answer as an Answer, instead of editing the answer into the question